# how to write a global function for all catch block and each catch block can pass its own custom messages as parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, closures, hoisting

## userComponent.js

```
 function users(userService, helperService) {
        return userService.get()
       .then(function(){})
       .catch(function (errors) {
             if (angular.isArray(errors)) {
        for (var i = errors.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            console.log(errors[i]);
        }
    }
    window.alert('unable to get data');
        });
    }
```

## userService.js

```
 function get() {
    return dataService.get("users").then(function (data) {
        if (....) {
            return data
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('error in userService')
        }
    }).catch(helperService.ErrorHandler('error in userService'));
}
```

## dataService.js

```
function get(endpoint, data) {
        return $http.get(API_URL + endpoint).then(function (data) {
            if (status check) {
                return data;
            }
            else {
                throw new Error('error in dataService')
            }
        }).catch(helperService.ErrorHandler('error in dataService'));
    }
```

## helperService

```
function ErrorHandler (error) {

};
```

I need to write single ErrorHandler function for all catch block and return a array to userComponent.js.. (using javascript closure and hoisting properties..)

Comment: rookie mistake: `.catch(helperService.ErrorHandler('error in dataService'));` won't do what you expect. `.catch` requires a function as an argument, you are supplying the result of (immediately) calling a function as the argument, you'll want something along the lines of `.catch((err) => helperService.ErrorHandler('error in dataService'));`